# SQL database not showing. Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

I’m trying to bring [Adopt a Hydrant](https://github.com/codeforamerica/adopt-a-hydrant) to Helsinki.

So far I've managed to change the location of the map to Helsinki, build a database with postgreSQL, set the private key and deploy the app in heroku (the app is available at [paloposti.herokuapp.com](http://paloposti.herokuapp.com)).

However no hydrants are showing in the map. I’ve replaced all the latitudes and longitutes in the seeds.rb file and run:

```
bundle exec rake db:create
bundle exec rake db:schema:load
rake db:setup
bundle exec rake db:seed
```

I’m sure I’m missing something very stupid, but what?

my logs :

```
    2015-08-15T11:47:39.043348+00:00 app[web.1]:       ORDER BY distance
    2015-08-15T11:47:39.043351+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
    2015-08-15T11:47:39.043353+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/thing.rb:22:in `find_closest'
    2015-08-15T11:47:39.043354+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/things_controller.rb:5:in `show'
    2015-08-15T11:47:39.043355+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-08-15T11:47:39.043357+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.856659+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/things.json?utf8=%E2%9C%93&lat=60.180887&lng=24.94053800000006" host=paloposti.herokuapp.com request_id=568f316d-88c7-4fae-9d00-697994614ba9 fwd="82.214.17.63" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=500 bytes=245
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.848768+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/things.json?utf8=%E2%9C%93&lat=60.180887&lng=24.94053800000006" for 82.214.17.63 at 2015-08-15 11:50:07 +0000
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.850481+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "lat"=>"60.180887", "lng"=>"24.94053800000006"}
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.852069+00:00 app[web.1]:   Thing Load (0.8ms)        SELECT *, (3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(60.180887)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(lng) - RADIANS(24.94053800000006)) + SIN(RADIANS(60.180887)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat)))) AS distance
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.852071+00:00 app[web.1]:       FROM things
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.852074+00:00 app[web.1]:       LIMIT 10
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.852076+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.852109+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "things" does not exist
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.852110+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 2:       FROM things
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.852112+00:00 app[web.1]:                    ^
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.852116+00:00 app[web.1]:       FROM things
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.852117+00:00 app[web.1]:       ORDER BY distance
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.852118+00:00 app[web.1]:       LIMIT 10
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.850436+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ThingsController#show as JSON
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.852073+00:00 app[web.1]:       ORDER BY distance
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.852245+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.852115+00:00 app[web.1]: :       SELECT *, (3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(60.180887)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(lng) - RADIANS(24.94053800000006)) + SIN(RADIANS(60.180887)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat)))) AS distance
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.852120+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.853033+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.853036+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "things" does not exist
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.853038+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 2:       FROM things
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.853039+00:00 app[web.1]:                    ^
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.853040+00:00 app[web.1]: :       SELECT *, (3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(60.180887)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(lng) - RADIANS(24.94053800000006)) + SIN(RADIANS(60.180887)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat)))) AS distance
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.853042+00:00 app[web.1]:       FROM things
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.853043+00:00 app[web.1]:       ORDER BY distance
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.853044+00:00 app[web.1]:       LIMIT 10
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.853046+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.853047+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/thing.rb:22:in `find_closest'
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.853048+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/things_controller.rb:5:in `show'
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.853050+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-08-15T11:50:07.853051+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.578442+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/things.json?utf8=%E2%9C%93&lat=60.180887&lng=24.94053800000006" host=paloposti.herokuapp.com request_id=03a40dd8-6fdd-4a34-8258-b37583c1d490 fwd="82.214.17.63" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=500 bytes=245
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.569835+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/things.json?utf8=%E2%9C%93&lat=60.180887&lng=24.94053800000006" for 82.214.17.63 at 2015-08-15 11:50:12 +0000
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.573575+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 2:       FROM things
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.573578+00:00 app[web.1]: :       SELECT *, (3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(60.180887)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(lng) - RADIANS(24.94053800000006)) + SIN(RADIANS(60.180887)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat)))) AS distance
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.573580+00:00 app[web.1]:       FROM things
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.573581+00:00 app[web.1]:       ORDER BY distance
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.573583+00:00 app[web.1]:       LIMIT 10
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.573536+00:00 app[web.1]:   Thing Load (1.3ms)        SELECT *, (3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(60.180887)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(lng) - RADIANS(24.94053800000006)) + SIN(RADIANS(60.180887)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat)))) AS distance
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.573584+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.573542+00:00 app[web.1]:       LIMIT 10
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.573573+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "things" does not exist
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.571510+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ThingsController#show as JSON
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.574536+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "things" does not exist
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.573540+00:00 app[web.1]:       ORDER BY distance
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.571537+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "lat"=>"60.180887", "lng"=>"24.94053800000006"}
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.573543+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.573709+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.574539+00:00 app[web.1]:                    ^
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.574534+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.574541+00:00 app[web.1]: :       SELECT *, (3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(60.180887)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(lng) - RADIANS(24.94053800000006)) + SIN(RADIANS(60.180887)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat)))) AS distance
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.574538+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 2:       FROM things
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.574542+00:00 app[web.1]:       FROM things
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.574543+00:00 app[web.1]:       ORDER BY distance
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.573576+00:00 app[web.1]:                    ^
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.573539+00:00 app[web.1]:       FROM things
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.574545+00:00 app[web.1]:       LIMIT 10
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.574548+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/thing.rb:22:in `find_closest'
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.574546+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.574550+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.574551+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.574549+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/things_controller.rb:5:in `show'
    2015-08-15T11:50:12.886199+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=paloposti.herokuapp.com request_id=0f37c35f-4795-453f-8f43-2b51fd0533f5 fwd="82.214.17.63" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=736
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.655695+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/things.json?utf8=%E2%9C%93&lat=60.180887&lng=24.94053800000006" for 82.214.17.63 at 2015-08-15 11:50:13 +0000
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.657311+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ThingsController#show as JSON
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.657318+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "lat"=>"60.180887", "lng"=>"24.94053800000006"}
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.659033+00:00 app[web.1]:   Thing Load (1.0ms)        SELECT *, (3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(60.180887)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(lng) - RADIANS(24.94053800000006)) + SIN(RADIANS(60.180887)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat)))) AS distance
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.659036+00:00 app[web.1]:       FROM things
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.659037+00:00 app[web.1]:       ORDER BY distance
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.659038+00:00 app[web.1]:       LIMIT 10
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.659040+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.659066+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "things" does not exist
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.659067+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 2:       FROM things
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.659069+00:00 app[web.1]:                    ^
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.659070+00:00 app[web.1]: :       SELECT *, (3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(60.180887)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(lng) - RADIANS(24.94053800000006)) + SIN(RADIANS(60.180887)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat)))) AS distance
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.659072+00:00 app[web.1]:       FROM things
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.659073+00:00 app[web.1]:       ORDER BY distance
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.659075+00:00 app[web.1]:       LIMIT 10
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.659076+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.659209+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.659999+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.660004+00:00 app[web.1]:                    ^
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.660006+00:00 app[web.1]: :       SELECT *, (3959 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS(60.180887)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(lng) - RADIANS(24.94053800000006)) + SIN(RADIANS(60.180887)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat)))) AS distance
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.660001+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "things" does not exist
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.660003+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 2:       FROM things
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.660007+00:00 app[web.1]:       FROM things
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.660009+00:00 app[web.1]:       ORDER BY distance
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.660011+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.660010+00:00 app[web.1]:       LIMIT 10
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.660013+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/thing.rb:22:in `find_closest'
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.660015+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/things_controller.rb:5:in `show'
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.660016+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.660017+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.663608+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/things.json?utf8=%E2%9C%93&lat=60.180887&lng=24.94053800000006" host=paloposti.herokuapp.com request_id=e523b244-725d-4671-82db-2555d0836704 fwd="82.214.17.63" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=500 bytes=245
    2015-08-15T11:50:13.876213+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=paloposti.herokuapp.com request_id=f81408cd-cdc4-4c6b-afda-a4d8633bf033 fwd="82.214.17.63" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=736
```

Comment: One of the scripts on your page (http://paloposti.herokuapp.com/things.json?utf8=%E2%9C%93&lat=60.180887&lng=24.94053800000006 ) is causing a internal server error. Check the logs on Heroku (`heroku logs`) and add any relevant error messages to the question.

Comment: Try opening up the rails console `heroku run rails c`.  Then run `Thing.count` and see if you actually have any records in the database. Also make sure you check the browser console - the issue could just as well be caused by a script error or something not related to the db at all.

Comment: I’m getting this error: 
`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "things" does not exist`

Comment: Make sure you have run the migrations on heroku: `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: When I now run thing count I get this:
`CMac:paloposti costantin$ heroku run rails c --app paloposti
Running rails c attached to terminal... up, run.7221
[SKYLIGHT] [0.8.0] authentication token required; disabling Skylight agent
Loading production environment (Rails 4.2.3)
irb(main):001:0> Thing.count
   (1.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "things"
   (1.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "things"
=> 0
irb(main):002:0> `

Comment: I’ve upload the app tho Github: https://github.com/CostantinB/adopt-a-hydrant

Comment: When you run `bundle exec rake db:seed`. You are actually just running it on your local machine. So to seed to the database on heroku you would run `heroku run rake db:seed`.

Comment: Awesome, it worked thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `bundle exec rake db:seed`. You are actually just running it on your local machine. So to seed to the database on heroku you would run `heroku run rake db:seed`.